# Can't create cq node when include a CQ5 component

Tags: java, jsp, aem, jackrabbit, sling

I use below code to include help component to my page.

```
 <cq:include path="help" resourceType="/apps/me/components/nav/help" />
```

The page display ok but when i check

```
crx/de/index.jsp
```

I can't find 'help' node in the repository. After that i open the page and edit help component, check CRX again and i found 'help' node was created.  Is it possible if we create 'help' node without edit itself.

Comment: Why do you want the help node to be available even before it is authored?

Comment: check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392147/cq5-preload-a-parsys-with-components/22400783#22400783 .If you want the node to be there when the page is created, you need to add it into the template you use to create the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer about preloading a parsys with components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392147/cq5-preload-a-parsys-with-components/22400783#22400783). You can use a Page template.

You probably used the siteadmin to create that page using a template. You just need to add to the template definition any node that needs to be copied into a page when it is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the node is define yet. If the node is not define, you must create it.